# search list of string with wildcard and return matches & indexes python

Tags: python, regex, string, wildcard

given a list

```
list=['beak','back','bear','kill','keel']
```

I'd like to perform a search with a wild card to return all words that match the pattern `k**l` for example. I can easily to this with the following:

```
regex=re.compile('k..l')
matches=[string for string in list if re.match(regex, string)]
```

However, I'd also like to access the index of the position of the matches and have something like that:

```
matches=kill, keel
locs=3,4
```

The reason why I want the indexes is that once the matches found I'd like to access a full row (containing other variables) in a df.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are OK with tuples of matches and indices, you can use `[(idx, string) for idx, string in enumerate(list) if re.match(regex, string)]`. Then you can use `zip` to separate the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in my comment, you can combine `enumerate` and `zip` to achieve your goal:

```
import re

lst=['beak','back','bear','kill','keel']
regex=re.compile('k..l')
locs, matches = zip(*[(idx, string) for idx, string in enumerate(lst) if re.match(regex, string)])
print(matches)
print(locs)
```

Comment: Excellent! I just made an edit (which still needs to be peer-reviewed) and changed the order of the outputs because it was storing indexes and strings in the wrong outputs. Works great though, thanks!